# Jenkins post build tasks running at the wrong time

Tags: jenkins, post-build-event

I've got a Jenkins build, that appears to be working very well. I've now added some Post build tasks to it, in order to automatically deploy the web app onto one of our development servers.

Since I have done that, I have seen some extremely bizarre behaviour. The Post-build tasks appear to be running before the build, as if they were pre-build tasks.

**Logs**

<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
SSH: Connecting from host [HOST_NAME]
SSH: Connecting with configuration [Development Web Server] ...
SSH: Disconnecting configuration [Development Web Server] ...
SSH: Transferred 1 file(s)
Build step 'Send files or execute commands over SSH' changed build result to SUCCESS
SSH: Connecting from host [HOST_NAME]
SSH: Connecting with configuration [Development Web Server] ...
SSH: Disconnecting configuration [Development Web Server] ...
SSH: Transferred 0 file(s)
SSH: Connecting from host [HOST_NAME]
SSH: Connecting with configuration [Development Web Server] ...
SSH: EXEC: STDOUT/STDERR from command [chmod +x

These logs are being generated before the build is ever ran, and obviously because the build does not exist, it is failing to find the necessary files.

Answer (score 0):

Just tested it, and the issue seems to have resolved itself. Bizarre, but hey!